# With an Australian travel document for refugees, do I need a visa to enter Germany?

Tags: visas, germany, belgium, refugees

I have an Australian travel document for refugees. Do I need a visa to travel to Germany?  From there, will I be able to travel to Belgium ?

Comment: When you say "Stay in Belgium", do you mean in a hotel, or that you want to start living there?

Comment: Traveling to Germany is a very different question from moving to Belgium.  For the latter, you should ask on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: I want to stay in Belgium and live there.

Comment: Stay in Belgium and apply to the asylum.

Comment: I choose Germany because it is near to Belgium,  and I know if I want to apply for asylum in any European country, I mustnt go to that country directly.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around?  You are supposed to apply for asylum in the first EU country you reach.  But since you already have asylum in Austria, you aren't going to be able to get it elsewhere (except in the unlikely event that Austria is no longer safe for you, I suppose).  Anyway, asylum is off topic here, go to [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: How many places does one need to be granted Asylum to be safe?

Comment: @phoog Australia != Austria

Comment: @CMaster I need new glasses, apparently.

Comment: @CMaster the OP is Australia; might he actually mean Austria?

Comment: @phoog You can apply for asylum wherever you want. It's only once you have applied that the Dublin system becomes relevant. Belgium will most likely try to force Germany (or whichever country issued the visa) to take you and process the application or possibly even to send you to Australia (that would be unrelated to Dublin obviously) but that does not mean they would be successful. Of course, entering through another country does make that somewhat more likely I would think, but the system is broken and unpredictable.

Comment: I've edited the part about asylum out of your question as I believe the first part is on-topic for this site. You should still consider asking on [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) for the asylum process

Comment: Austria is next to Germany, while Australia is thousands of kilometers away. Are you sure you meant Australia? Or to put it another way: does your country have kangaroos outside of zoos?

Comment: I expect that you are very likely to be refused asylum anywhere in the EU on the grounds that you've already obtained asylum from Australia.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is **no, you don't need a visa** to go to Germany with your Australian Travel Document.

From the [Germany embassy](http://www.australien.diplo.de/Vertretung/australien/en/Visa/Schengen-Visa.html) in Australia:

> The same applies to holders of Australian travel documents for
>   refugees (Convention of 28 July 1951) and stateless persons
>   (Convention of 28 September 1954): They can enter Germany without a
>   visa for an intended stay of up to 90 days, as long as at the time of
>   entry into Germany their travel document is still valid for at least 4
>   months.

Once you're in Germany you can freely travel in the Schengen area which includes Belgium.