# Which European countries can I visit visa-free on an Australian travel document for refugees?

Tags: schengen, europe, paperwork, refugees

I have an Australian travel document for refugees, which European countries am I allowed to visit without a Schengen visa ?

Comment: What have you found so far with your own research ?

Comment: Didn't you ask us this question -- and get an answer -- last week?

Comment: Related (courtesy of Relaxed): http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46413/travelling-through-the-schengen-area-with-a-refugee-travel-document-issued-by-th

Comment: Also related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80290/with-an-australian-travel-document-for-refugees-do-i-need-a-visa-to-enter-germa